# Not able to read the property file

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, resin

I am working on one web application in which i want to retrieve values from property files which are present outside of the application i.e on system drive.
but while doing this i am facing the problem.Interestingly if i put property files at class path location then application works properly.
 I am using resin server 3.0.23 and spring mvc architecture with spring 2.5.4 jars.i am also tried it on resin upgraded version of resin 4.0.9. there also i am getting the same problem.

Is there any compatibility issue of resin server for above query or If there is any other way to solve this issue?

please suggest.

thanks.

Comment: what is the actual problem is it trying to look at some other place ? or on relative path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a properties file from an arbitrary path on the system you need to do something like

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream(somefilename));
```

If you are trying to load the properties file with calls to `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()`, your properties file should be somewhere accessible from a ClassLoader, usually on the classpath. Check the docs for [Class.getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) and [ClassLoader.getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))